# Hibernate, get child object from abstract parent

Tags: java, hibernate, oop, hql, object-oriented-database

I am getting a parent abstract object from hibernate. What is the best way to get true child object?

I think this is not a correct way to do it:

```
Long parentId=parent.getId();
Child child=childMgr.getInstance().getById(parentId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Child should be already declared in your Parent object class:

```
public class parent{
    private Child child ;
//setter getter
}
```

then in your parent hbm (varies if using annotation) you map it:

```
<one-to-one cascade="none" name="child" not-null="true"
        class="com.example.child" 
        column="FOREIGN_KEY" />
```

Then once you have the parent you can just call:

```
Child child = parent.getChild();
```

This only applies if you have one to one relationship, varies for one to many, will need to set as list.

Comment: @AhmadReza please accept or upvote answer if it has been helpful

Comment: if parent have several different child,this method is little complex! . are you have any idea without changing in hbm files?

Comment: Use annotations in stead of XML config files? Your question is very vague.

Comment: @melt321 i define child as _Object Type_ `public class parent{ private Object child;}` and then with `if(parent.getChild() instanceof Child)` cast appropriate offspring  to _parent.getChild()_. so i accept your answer!